# Etckeeper + git and remote server

Tags: linux, git, branch, push

Is it some possible to clone etckeeper git repo on my computer, make some changes and after that push to /etc folder on server?

I tried this but i have problem with push because etc is noa a bare repo.

Thanks for help.

BR,

Answer (score 0):

You would have to either pull repo on etckeeper machine from your computed, or use intermediate bare repo like that:
your pc --(push)--> remote repo
etckeeper machine <--(pull)-- remote repo

Answer (score 0):

With [keepconf](https://github.com/rfrail3/keepconf) tool you can get the files from remote servers and track them locally into a git repo.